# If and Match statements in an excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I have to columns in excel (`A` and `B`) as follows:

[image]

with text phrases inside. I want to check if a the the phrases of `B` exists in the `A` column. If exists, then to print the phrase, if not to print blank cell. The final result must be

[image]

How can i do that in Excel?

Comment: Try adapting `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$6,0)),B1,"")`. This is too basic. See [MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XLOOKUP()` like-

```
=XLOOKUP(B1:B6,A1:A6,A1:A6,"",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Do we need the fifth argument (`0`)? this is the default value, right?

Comment: We can omit that one.